# Detail Disclosure Button and Segues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using a UITableViewController that performs an action sheet upon click, which works great. I'd like to tie the Detail Disclosure to a segue. I created a segue from the cell to the next table, and added the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GroupToGroupMembers" sender:self];
}
```

Works great when I tap the Detail Disclosure.

Problem is, tapping on the cell now causes both the action sheet AND the segue to fire off, which I would expect.

Anyone figure out how to fire off a segue off of a detail disclosure **only**?

Comment: What do you mean by action sheet?

Comment: `UIActionSheet` class and delegate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably have the "GroupToGroupMembers" segue hooked up to your UITableViewCell.  When you do this, the segue is automatically performed when the cell is selected.  This happening in addition to your regular event handling which is showing the action sheet.

Hook your segue up to your UITableViewController instead.  This allows you to define your segue so that it may be performed in response to the DetailDisclosure being tapped while, at the same time, preventing the segue from being automatically performed when a cell is selected.

Comment: Bingo. Thanks a lot, I didn't realize I could just connect at the controller itself, makes it a lot easier.

Comment: created an "unsupported configuration" warning for me. You don't get it??

Comment: Your recommendation produces an "unsupported configuration" warning. Any clues? EDIT: I got it. I needed to set the identifier. One should read the warning details before posting a comment :) sorry.