# IndexPath for segue from accessoryButton

Tags: iphone, storyboard

I am attempting to use a storyboard/segue to handle the transition between a UITableView with both standard transition as well as detail disclosure button. Having read a few different posts on here I have set up my project this way:

1. Tie main segue between UITableViewCell and ViewController
2. Tie secondary segue from parent ViewController to new ViewController
3. Implement `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` as follows:

   ```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailSegue" sender:self];
   }
   ```

This works great and my `prepareForSegue: sender:` gets called as expected. The trouble is, I need to know the indexPath for the element selected. The segue from the UITableViewCell retrieves the indexPath like this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

Unfortunately when I try to do that having called the accessoryButton, that returns `null`.

The original question I am basing some of this code off of is here: [Detail Disclosure Button and Segues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087389/detail-disclosure-button-and-segues)

Is there a method of the tableView which returns indexPath for accessoryButtons? Do I need to access the indexPath in some other manner?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't have to override `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath`.

In `prepareForSegue`, when working with a detail disclosure button, instead of:

```
[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]
```

use:

```
[self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender]
```

The sender is already the detail disclosure button's cell.

Comment: When I did this, sender was the TableViewController I was in.
So in performSegue, I passed the cell as the sender

Comment: how do we do this in Swift 3?

Answer (score 13):

The `sender` argument is, according to the documentation:

> The object that you want to use to initiate the segue. This object is made available for informational purposes during the actual segue.

I don't see any reason why you can't use the index path as the sender instead of `self`, then access the index path in `prepareForSegue:`.

If that doesn't work, store the index path in an ivar and access that in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: Passing the indexPath as the sender works fine. Seems quite obvious once someone mentions it. Thanks.

Comment: Great idea, I was disturbed to think we might need a local variable just to pass this info across